# Unable to continue after cropping a image in CropActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, crop

I am using ArthurHub's library to crop a image and put it in a ImageButton or ImageView.
Crop Activity starts smoothly but after cropping when I clicks to CROP button, my app reruns and opens MainActivity.
It seems to me that there is no error in the code and also I have  checked it 5-6 times.

Thanks!!!

Here is my code...

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageButton add_image_button;

private Uri imageUri;
private String imageUrl;

private String recordPermission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
private String readExternalStorage = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
private String recordFile;
private int PERMISSION_CODE = 7;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    add_image_button = findViewById(R.id.add_image_button);
    
    CropImage.activity(imageUri).start(AddActivity.this);

    add_image_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            checkReadExternalStoragePermissions();
            CropImage.activity(imageUri).start(AddActivity.this);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        imageUri = result.getUri();

        add_audio_button.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Try again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(AddActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}

private boolean checkRecordPermissions() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, recordPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{recordPermission}, PERMISSION_CODE);
        return false;
    }

}
private boolean checkReadExternalStoragePermissions() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, readExternalStorage) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{readExternalStorage}, PERMISSION_CODE);
        return false;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: If the activity is crashing, there must be an error, just the android studio's logcat isn't showing it, happened with me, you can use terminal and type adb logcat to see it. Second, if it's not crashing, it might be returning the result in the onActivityResult, have your tried logging whether it is called or not?

Comment: @Lalit Fauzdar your second case suits my problem, but I don't understand what are you talking about in that case, can you explain more?

Comment: When you press the crop button and it comes back to the previous activity without crashing means it returns the data correctly, you just can't parse/access it correctly, so log the result in your function `onActivityResult` and see whether it actually returns the data or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the error, there was a slight mistake in the code.

I used `add_audio_button.setImageUri(imageUri)` instead of `add_image_button.setImageUri(imageUri);` here:

```
if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
    imageUri = result.getUri();
    add_audio_button.setImageURI(imageUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.github.Drjacky:ImagePicker:1.8.4'
```

use this library it is one of best for imagePicker
it will be give functionality like
1)crop
2)zoom
3)rotate